# Mini private key format

Tags: private-key, mini-key

I want to understand why the format for a mini private key necessarily has to start with an "S". Why is this? Is there a specific reason for it? I would imagine so, but I don't know what it might be.

Answer (score 2):

It was not obligatory but the creator of the mini private key Mike Caldwell decided to use this system of using an S before to help users distinguish between regular private keys and mini private keys.

notice that it is not recommended to use those type of key because they are less secure than regular private key, also the S stand for Spend

Comment: Thank you very much for replying

Comment: @reticus you welcome, dont forget to validate the answer if you satisfied with it